# ColdFusion: Query VS Structures

Tags: performance, optimization, coldfusion, structure, cfquery

Currently, I've a query inside a loop as below.

```
<cfloop query="Superquery">
    <cfquery datasource="mysource" name="getData">
        SELECT col1, Col2
        FROM myData
        where col1 = #Superquery.IDCol#
    </cfquery>
    <!--- Some Processing --->
</cfloop>
```

The query doesn't return much data. In some cases, it returns less than 100 rows & in some it can return around 5000 rows. But since it is inside a loop & iterations can go over 100, it makes me think on a better optimization approach.

**Approach 1: Use Query of Queries**

```
<cfquery datasource="mysource" name="getAllData">
        SELECT col1, Col2
        FROM myData
</cfquery>
<cfloop query="Superquery">
    <cfquery dbtype="query" name="getData">
        SELECT col1, Col2
        FROM getAllData
        where col1 = #Superquery.IDCol#
    </cfquery>
    <!--- Some Processing --->
</cfloop>
```

**Approach 2: Use Structues**

Outside the loop, I've the query **getAllData** as per Approach 1 and  create a structure with Key as 'col1' and Value as 'col2'. Inside the loop, I use the sturcture that was created outside the loop to do the necessary processing.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference in performance between the two approaches. Approach 1 is easy to implement though. :) Just thought of getting some suggestions. Any other efficient approaches are welcome.

Thank you!!

Comment: Approach Number 3 would probably be the most efficient.  That's the one where you figure out a way to avoid the loop altogether.  The details depend on a number of things, starting with superquery and getalldata use the same datasource.

Comment: Are you suggesting me to include a DB table since it is using the same datasource? For the looping part, I actually set some Array variables in the loop and use it for further processing later on. I can't think of a way where the loop is avoidable in this case. What all details does it depand on?

Comment: To Dan's point, you are going to want to to a `JOIN` or something. Approach 1 is just begging for performance and memory usage issues. (Also if you insist on doing one use `<cfqueryparam>`

Comment: The details depend on what you are trying to do.  However, if all tables are in the same database, it is often more efficient to to get all the data you need with one query.  However, often is not the same as always.  Another alternative to having a query inside a loop is to run a Q of Q using a ValueList and looping through those results..

Comment: Option 3, as others have noted should be the uses of `JOINS`

Comment: I would agree with Dan and Scott, however Q of a Q is often "good enough." Test it and see. you might get gains based on networking and/or how busy your DB server is. If you do, great, if not, try refactoring with a join.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion Guys. I'm implementing the same & will let you know in case of any performace gain..

Comment: Hello Guys! After a implementing the fix, here is my observation done throughout the week: Whenever we include a query inside a loop, it issues a "Create Statement" for each query to be executed for each iteration. So, if the loop runs 1000 times & there is no conditional logic for query execution, 1000 "Create statements" are issued to database. This increases I/O time. As suggested, I've implemeted joins thereby eliminating the need to include the query inside the loop & thus reducing I/O time. If the number iterations is very large, this I/O time could be very siginificant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query of queries is actually pretty slow compared to an SQL query as it doesn't have any concept of indexes or execution plans so you need to be careful before going down that route as you could well end up with a slower more intensive process. Database engines are optimised to do this kind of thing fast.

You may well find that using a struct will perform better, but you do have the overhead of creating the structure. Unfortunately I can't give you a one-size fits all answer, as it depends on your data and the volumes.

Ideally you want to be able to do a join between `myData` and the tables that create your `Superquery` query. You can then iterate over that query and process as you need without hitting the database again.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a structure seems to complicate things. 
Query is itself a structure of arrays. 
So whatever you want to accomplish by creating another structure, you can do it using query too. 
And structure over query of query doesn't seems to have any added advantage. 
If you really want to optimize things, better try to modify your query. 
For example as others said you can try using some sort of `JOIN` in your query to get rid of loop.